# Email clients behave different while attaching images

Tags: android

I have following code, I am attaching an image from res folder and sending it, In Samsung Galaxy S2 , I have two email clients default samsung and gmail one. When I send an email, I receive correct file with extension as .png when I send it from gmail, however if I send it from default email client .png is missing in attachment and I had to rename the file to see it. 
*Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);*

```
    emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
```

//        String rawFolderPath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() 
//                               + "/" + R.raw.test;

```
    Uri emailUri = Uri.parse(rawFolderPath );
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, emailUri);
    emailIntent.setType("image/png");

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "send email using"));
```

what should be solution??

Comment: Try sending a local file instead of a resource. Not all email clients might support attaching a resource image.

Comment: Email clients support attachment from resource, but if I don't specify extension it's just attaching image without extension and @recipient client I have to explicitly rename and see the content, however if I specify the extension in raw folder path , the attached image is 0 bytes. I tried putting image in data folder and sending even then its 0 bytes.

Comment: @techjeevi did you figure out the issue? I have a similar issue. :(